# Splitting or extracting numbers from column in R dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, split, extract

My dataframe is one column and goes like:

```
    df<- data.frame(col = c(
    "cat-dog-cat999-dog dog-mouse 23", 
    "dog2-cat45-mouse-cat 7",
    "dog 4",
    "dog6-dog-cat3-cat 6")
    )
```

I want to end with a column with only the last digits in each row, so the output would have the column

```
(23,
7,
4,
6 )
```

I think there are two options: either split at the last number preceded with a space or split at the last number in each raw.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your ideas are not bad. Have you tried to execute them? Any problems during the process? It'd be great if you also show us what have you tried and what are the problems when executing your ideas, we can learn together if you do it this way :)

Comment: Read the file with a space delimiter.

Comment: Do you want to keep the brackets? "(23" or just 23?

Comment: @zx8754 I edited the question now.. So you can see that there are many spaces the column..

Comment: Try: `sapply(strsplit(x, " ", fixed = TRUE), tail, n = 1)` Split on space, get last item.

Comment: @benson23 There are many functions and packages (gsub, stringr, readr, etc), but I can't find a function that allows a multiple delimiter (a space followed by a digit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the `str_extract()` function from `stringr` and `mutate` from `dplyr` - just loading `tidyverse` as this will load both `stringr` and `dplyr`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df<- data.frame(col = c("cat-dog-cat999-dog dog-mouse 23",
   "dog2-cat45-mouse-cat 7",
   "dog 4",
   "dog6-dog-cat3-cat 6")
)

df %>% 
  mutate(col = str_extract(col, "[0-9]*$") %>% 
           as.numeric())
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using sub. let's assume your data frame is like this:

```
df<- data.frame(A=c("cat-dog-cat999-dog dog-mouse 23", 
"dog2-cat45-mouse-cat 7",
"dog 4",
"dog6-dog-cat3-cat 6"))
```

Then you can use:

```
df %>%  mutate(new_column = sub(".* ", "", A))
```